# Converting SQL CASE WHEN statement into C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am on my first week of a summer programming internship and have been tasked with converting SQL Server 2008 statements into C# using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net). Once I do that and get it working properly, I can enter it into VS and tweak as needed.

The problem is that I am running across SQL statements I have no idea how to convert. In my C# class we did not convert SQL statements into C#, we just created a string variable, assigned the SQL statement to variable and then assigned the variable to an OleDbCommand object. My mentor took the day off for the long weekend and I'm pretty much on my own and clueless on what to do and need some help. There are a couple of dozen like this one and if I can see how to do one I can figure the rest out. Here is the SQL statement:

```
,[hrs].{Hours] - SUM(
  CASE 
    WHEN [UnitState].[UnitStateTye] <> 'ACTIVE' 
      THEN [Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] 
    ELSE 0 
  END 
/ CAST([Unit].[NetDependableCapacity] AS FLOAT)) AS SH
```

I'm pretty sure this is an if statement along the lines of:

```
if [UnitState].[UnitStateType] does not equal active 
then SH equals [hrs].[Hours] minus the the sum of
  [Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] / (float)[Unit].[NetDependableCapacity].  
else 
  SH = [hrs].[Hours]
```

I tried the following code, which I figured wasn't going to work but needed to start somewhere:

```
var results = 

    (from v in VDimUnit     
        join vf in VFactEnergyAllocation on v.UnitKey equals vf.UnitKey
        join vd in VDimGadsEvent on vf.GadsEventKey equals vd.GadsEventKey
        join vt in VDimTime on vf.TimeKey equals vt.TimeKey 
        join vus in VDimUnitState on vf.UnitKey equals vus.UnitKey
    where vd.GadsEventEndTime.Year == 2011 && v.UnitId == "THL3"
    group vf by new {vus.UnitStateType, vf.AllocatedEnergyMwh v.NetDependableCapacity,
        vt.QuarterNum} into groupItem       
    select new {groupItem.Key.QuarterNum, SUM1 = groupItem.Sum(x=> (float)x.AllocatedEnergyMwh /
        groupItem.Key.NetDependableCapacity)}).ToArray();

var resultHours = 
    (from v in VDimTime
    group v by v.QuarterNum into groupItem
    select new {Hours = groupItem.Count(), groupItem.Key}).ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x.Hours);

var finalResults = 
    (from r in results
    select new {SH_IF_NOT_ACTIVE = resultHours[r.QuarterNum] - r.SUM1,
        Hours = 
        SH_IF_ACTIVE = resultHours[r.QuarterNum]});

    if (SH != "ACTIVE")
    { 
        SH_IF_NOT_ACTIVE;
    }
    else
    {
        SH_IF_ACTIVE;
    }
```

I would appreciate it is someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: +1 for actually dping some work. So few new programmers arounod here seem to do that.

Comment: @ Michael Todd: I can't learn if I'm letting everyone else do it for me.  Not doing anything is not an option because I want a job with this company when I graduate. Plus they don't pay me to screw off.

Comment: The fist week is always the most painful. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Hours = condition ? code when true : code when false;
```