# How do I convert SQL Query with Ccase Switch to Linq Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

I am building a rest api in Visual Studio 2015, using MVC 6 and EF7.   I have a SQL Query that returns some specific data that I need.  It looks like this:

```
    SELECT jf.JournalID, jf.FileID, 
       CASE WHEN jf.Acknowledgment = 1 THEN 'Acknowledgment'
              WHEN jf.Foreword = 1 THEN 'Foreword'
              WHEN jf.Preface = 1 THEN 'Preface'
              WHEN jf.Logo = 1 THEN 'Logo'
              WHEN jf.Specialty = 1 THEN 'Specialty'
              WHEN jf.ContentsTable = 1 THEN 'Table of Contents'
              WHEN jf.TitlePage = 1 THEN 'Title Page'
              WHEN jf.AuthorIndex = 1 THEN 'Author Index'
              ELSE NULL 
               END AS ArticleType  
    FROM JournalFile jf 
    WHERE jf.JournalID = 19 --PARAMETER
```

I Need to convert this query to Linq, something like this:

```
  var results = (from s in _context.JournalFile
      where s.JournalID == jID
      select new IATTJService.Models.JournalFileTopLevel
          {
              JournalID = s.JournalID,
              FileID = s.FileID,
              ArticleType = ( 
                        << Case options Here >>
                             )
           }).ToList();
```

Each of the fields in the Case statements are Byte fields that return true or false.  I don't know how to execute the Case Section of the SQL in Linq.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761249/converting-sql-case-when-statement-into-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191414/using-case-statement-in-linq-query

Answer (score 2):

```
ArticleType = (
    jf.Acknowledgment == 1 ? 'Acknowledgment' :
    jf.Foreword == 1 ?  'Foreword' :
     // ect 
                         )
```

Comment: Hey bro, I was in a rush when editing mine and I already voted up yours for the intent of the code. Being syntactically right (he says bit fields) code should look like   jf.Acknowledgment == true ? "Acknowledgment"  OR shorter jf.Acknowledgment ? "Acknowledgment".

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = (from s in _context.JournalFile
      where s.JournalID == jID
      select new IATTJService.Models.JournalFileTopLevel
          {
              JournalID = s.JournalID,
              FileID = s.FileID,
              ArticleType = 
                 s.Acknowledgment ? "Acknowledgment"
                 : s.Foreword     ? "Foreword"
                 // ..
                 : AuthorIndex    ? "Author Index"
                 : null
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: It should be better now:)